# Migrate questions to Christianity.SE; don't just recommend it

Tags: discussion, migration

Today we had [yet another example](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/14109/529) of someone accidentally asking a question on BH.SE that actually belonged on Christianity.SE. "dæn" ;-) recommended to the OP that he ask it over on Christianity.SE, but is that really the best we can do?

In such cases, where it is clear to the team that the question belongs on our other site, I think we ought to migrate it over there for them, and not just make the recommendation.  Here are some good reasons for doing this:

- The OP doesn't know / have access to migrate it, so they'll have to manually create the new question over there. This means we're making things more difficult than they need to be for our "customers".
- Christianity.SE shows users this kind of courtesy, and as a sort of "big brother site" to ours, I think we should follow suit
- By migrating it ourselves, not only are we introducing the user to Christianity.SE, but we are also **advertising** BH.SE on that higher-volume site

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking that moderators (who can migrate currently) do so rather than making the recommendation or if you're asking that the community be able to do it *sans* moderator intervention. If the latter, you may want to check out [Make migration paths just another Off Topic reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215054/272257).

Comment: @Susan The former.

Comment: Got it. The question you point to appears to me to be suitable for neither C.SE or BH.SE in its current format. Although I'm not the moderator who knows the most about C.SE....I think it would be considered a ["truth question"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527/13677). With a little doctrinal scoping, it could work there. Then again, with a little textual focusing, it could work here. As such, I agree with Dan's decision to suggest the OP think more about his question and decide which direction he wants to go.

Comment: As for making things difficult for our "customers".... if a question is migrated and then placed "on hold" at the receiving site pending edits, (except in the case of duplicates) the migration is "rejected" and it's back here. (AFAIK, this is how SE set it up and there's nothing we can do about it.) This seems like even more frustration for the OP who is left thinking that we both a) don't like his question and b) don't know what we're doing. If it's not ready "as is" to go forward on the accepting site, I think it doesn't make sense to migrate.

Comment: @Susan It seems like those problems would be solved if the moderator were willing to also do some minor editing. I just think our policy needs to be to assist new users in getting answers, and we need to avoid simply closing their questions and suggesting they go somewhere else and do more work.

Comment: @Susan Imagine you're a new user and had that happen. Would you want to continue participating? The first time I contributed on this site I was very nervous, but my post was well-received so I became more confident and continued to participate.

Comment: Personally, I don't feel equipped to edit stuff to make it suitable for C.SE. I'm sure Caleb does; Dan might. But I don't think that's our job. If we don't think it's suitable for another site and it isn't suitable for our site, it should be placed on hold with as much friendly advice as both the mods and other users can muster. Although I appreciate your points about being friendly, the advice from SE is consistently: [if in doubt, close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119115/272257).

Comment: By the way, *you* are a high rep user on C.SE. If you want to edit something to make it work there and then flag it for migration, by all means....even after a mod has put it on hold as off-topic here, I think any of us would welcome such a flag.

Comment: @Susan Granted. I was hoping for more of a "site policy" of such consideration though. I'm concerned that we're doing a good job protecting the site, but not as good a job being helpful and considerate to new users.

Comment: @Jas3.1 I used to make such edits a lot. After being accused of totally changing the OP's intent (which often *is* to ask an off topic question), and being accused of all manner of things - I've found that I'll never make everyone happy. The first priority is to close something that is off topic. If a minor edit can make it on topic, perhaps I will. But in this case it would totally change the OP's intent - so I want to have them on board first. And in this case, it's not ready for migration. A doctrinal perspective on end times is missing. The OP has never replied nor edited in this case.

Comment: Who is qualified to migrate a question... and how is it done? Is there a procedure to appeal a decision to migrate it?